# HTML default Browse value

Tags: php, html

Is it possible to set a default value in a 'file browse' option in HTML/PHP? For example:

```
<b>Enter Image:</b></font><input type="file" name="ima" accept="image/gif">
```

Can i set a default file name within this?

Comment: Why not set the default value in the submit handler (the script which handles the file upload)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - Since it will be a security issue. Consider setting the default to `/etc/passwd` and the person pressing submit.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're file name will be relative to the computer running the code, I'm not sure it would be beneficial to do this. As far as I know you cannot for this reason.